# Calling besides the point 'x' and point 'y' in highstock

Tags: highcharts

Suppose there is a point in the data highstock 'x', 'y' and 'b', if we want to point 'y' in the tooltip we can call by calling point.y, how to call point.b ?

Thank's

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can you put up a JSFiddle with an example?

Comment: @Nina : this is my example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/priow2013/Vbynb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `point.options.b` to get your custom point options.
Remember, that in Highstock you have dataGrouping, which will NOT group custom options.

Comment: can you give me example please ? because i use data array like this var data = [
[x:Date.UTC(2003,8,24),y:0.8709,b:"ab"],
[x:Date.UTC(2003,8,25),y:0.872,b:"cd"],
[x:Date.UTC(2003,8,26),y:0.8714,b:"ef"],
[x:Date.UTC(2003,8,29),y:0.8638,b:"gh"],
[x:Date.UTC(2003,8,30),y:0.8567,b:"ij"],
[x:Date.UTC(2003,9,1),y:0.8536,b:"kl"]
];
But the chart is not showing